# How to setup developer environment for rosjava(android)

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, there

I am having trouble with setting up developer environment for android app using rosjava.
Could anyone explain me how to create a rosjava(android) project and compile it? Or address me to the good tutorial for beginner?

I was trying to follow the tutorial code in repository(http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/android/tutorial) but they were not executable because of missing libraries..

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10579/how-to-setup-developer-environment-for-rosjava(android)/) by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 634 on 2011-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Documentation for this hasn't been compiled yet since the process is still very much in flux.

That being said, you should be able to build the sample Android projects by simply pulling in the correct jars. Build rosjava then add rosjava.jar and the message jars (look in ~/.ros/rosjava) to your build path.

The rest of it is standard Android development.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1